# how to show wordpress logged in username in top menu

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I need to display username in the top menu of my website it is displayed but I want in top menu in place of login when the user is logged out it will show login and when the user is login it will show welcome username, I am new in WordPress

```
<?php global $current_user; wp_get_current_user(); ?>
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
 echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n"; echo 'User name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n"; 
} 
else { wp_loginout(); } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function yh_display_username_wp_menu( $menu_items ) {
    global $current_user;
    foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( strpos( $menu_item->title, '{{username}}' ) !== false ) {
            // Get username, otherwise set it to blank.
            if ( $current_user->display_name ) {
                $username = $current_user->display_name;
            } else {
                $username = '';
            }
                $menu_item->title =  str_replace( '{{username}}',  $username, $menu_item->title );
        }
    }
    return $menu_items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'yh_display_username_wp_menu' );
```

Once the code snippet is added, it will replace the variable {{username}} with the user’s display name. To add this variable to your WordPress menu please take the following steps:

Login to your WordPress dashboard.
Navigate to Appearance and select Menus.
Choose your menu you would like to add the username to.
Find or add a menu item you would like to show the username in and click on the dropdown arrow.
Edit the Link Text and add {{username}}
Save your menu.
Repeat this for each menu you would like to show the username in.

[image]